# What constitutes prior art in relation to this application?

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [CA2907779A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2907779A1)

I know for a fact that prototypes of the subject of this patent application were marketed to crop growers in California & Texas (as finished product), as well as displayed at relevant industry shows (eg: robotics shows, mining shows, agriculture shows, etc...) well before this patent was applied for - so wouldn't that constitute prior art?

If so, what would be the best way to advise the USPTO of this?

Comment: The (very) short answer is 'yes.' If something was out in the world, it's definitely a candidate for prior art. The first step would be to ensure you understand the existing application, and what exactly is being claimed, then to find concrete evidence (writings, videos, what have you) of the invention's existence. If you can compile a summary of what claims were already known along with that information, we'll be able to help you find the right place to send it all.